# Convert Windows.old into a virtual pc

Tags: windows, virtualization, microsoft-virtual-pc, vhd, boot-to-vhd

I have rebuilt my Windows 7 ultimate operating system. I performed the rebuild over the top of its self so it automatically moved my old operating system to a Windows.old directory.

I would like to try and create a virtual pc of my old installation. I have created a vhd file, mounted it and copied across the contents of windows.old. What additional steps do I need to do to make this vhd boot into my old windows?

Comment: I do not really know how should you step forward... but I suggest you try and rebuild the `bootcfg` on your virtual disk, if that identifies your windos installation as a valid OS, you can then fix the other things....

Comment: I presume you understand that, even if you *are* able to accomplish this, it will not re-create any of your user data in the VM.

Comment: Why wouldn't I be able to recreate the user data? I'm expecting to be able to login as it did before. That is once I have rebuilt the BCD and the HAL is reconfigured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this in the end, here is an overview of what I did.

- Create a vhd and mount it ([see guide](http://www.trainsignal.com/blog/how-do-i-create-and-mount-a-vhd-in-windows-7))
- Copy the contents of Windows.old to the mounted vhd
- Installed [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) (Microsoft Virtual PC cannot cope with 64 bit virtual clients)
- Unmounted the vhd from windows and used it to create a new Virtual Box instance
- Kicked off the new instance and booted to a windows 7 install cd
- Using the Windows 7 boot cd recovery options I opened a new command prompt
- Using Diskpart.exe I set my primary partition to be Active ([see guide](http://www.geeksdo.com/set-active-partition.html))
- Used Bootrec.exe to create a new MBR and rebuild the Boot Configuration Data (BCD) store ([see guide](http://kb.acronis.com/content/1507))

I was then able to boot into my vhd. My old windows 7 install then went through a number of automated driver updates due to the new virtual hardware configuration. After a few reboots it was fine though. Note, I did need to reactivate windows though due to the hardware changes.

Hope this helps anyone else trying to do the same.